# Setting up the Coordinates

Tags: javascript

i am facing the problem in setting up back the coordinates in javascript, i have already taken the coordinates using pageX and pageY, now the problem is this, that i want to set the image on to the coordinates which i have taken through pageX and pageY, please let me know ASAP, if anyone knows about the solution....Thanks in Advance....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this might help : http://api.jquery.com/offset/

or this http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_positioning.asp